# About deleting previous div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have question i.e how can i select a previous div
CODE:-

```
if($i > $start_from){
                echo "<div id=\"blog$i\"><h1 style=\"padding-top:30px; font-size:14px;\" id=\"shareContent\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">$title</a><br /></h1>
                $desc
                <br />
                <p><em>hahaquotes, DATED: $date, URL: <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">$url</a></em></p>
                <div class=\"applyLink\" style=\"width:720px; padding-right:12px; margin-top:20px;\">
                <p><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">READ</a><span style=\"float:right; cursor:pointer;\"><a class=\"delete\">DELETE</a></span></p>
                </div></div>";
                if($i == $start_from + 4) break; 
                }
                }
```

This is my code When i click on DELETE the whole div should be deleted the id for div is dynamically created how can i achive this using jquery. Please Help me Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't break a string across lines given the syntax that you are using. Look into heredocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a click handler to the anchor using the `delete` class as a selector. Within the handler `this` will refer to the clicked element, and from there you can traverse to the thing you want to delete without needing to know its id:

```
$("a.delete").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div").closest("div").remove();
});
```

The [`.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up through the DOM to find the closest ancestor matching the supplied selector. In your particular html structure the div you are looking for is the second-closest, so I've simply chained two invocations of `.closest()` together.

You can simplify this if you modify your html to give the div you want to remove a particular class, say "entry", because then you can traverse up to it with a single call to `.closest()` as follows:

```
echo "<div id=\"blog$i\" class=\"entry\">(etc.)"

$("a.delete").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div.entry").remove();
});
```

If you have several of these structures then each "delete" link would remove only the div that it belongs to.

Comment: How about `$(this).closest("div[id]").remove()`? Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks @Ajinkya, that would work too with no modifications to the html. I think you commented at the same time as I was editing to suggest adding a class to the div to be removed - a method I prefer because then the JS code would work even if the html structure changes, e.g., if the child div were later given an id - as long as the anchor is still a descendant of the main div...

Comment: Yup. Adding a class will be a good idea.

Comment: Thank You @nnnnnn adding a class is an good idea and its working...

Comment: @Ajinkya that's not a good idea because i have many more div's with id's

Comment: @TriveniGaikwad: It will select only closest div which have `id` attribute and not all. It will work for HTML given in question.

Comment: +1 for clarifying every step.

Answer (score 0):

you can use selector as

```
       $('div[id$="blog"]')
```

Comment: can u please explain this i dnt understood

Comment: If the divs are created in a loop and assigned sequential ids all starting with "blog" then this would select _all_ the divs, not just the one associated with the clicked link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parent div have `id` attribute and other `div` dont have `id` (as per your example).
you can use

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    $(this).parents("div[id]").remove();
 }):
```

**EDIT :**
Using `.closest()` instead of `.parents()` will be better and effective.

```
$(".delete").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("div[id]").remove();
 }):
```

Thanks to **nnnnnn**.

Comment: Might want to make it `.closest("div[id]")` as per your suggestion under my answer, because with `.parents()` it will keep going up beyond the structure we've been shown (there might be other ancestor divs that also have an id).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Thanks. `.closest` looks much better. I was not aware of `closest()`. I have updated my answer as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be like this :-

JQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.delete').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.parentPanel').remove();
    });

});
```

*EDIT: Changed `parentUntill()` to `closest()` as few of the mates informed and I do agree that `parentUntill()` selects the selecter 1step below the matched one. ** **Thanks nnnnnn**

The changed Code:- I have added a class named `parentPanel`

```
if($i > $start_from){
            echo "<div id=\"blog$i\" class=\"parentPanel\"><h1 style=\"padding-top:30px; font-size:14px;\" id=\"shareContent\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">$title</a><br /></h1>
            $desc
            <br />
            <p><em>hahaquotes, DATED: $date, URL: <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">$url</a></em></p>
            <div class=\"applyLink\" style=\"width:720px; padding-right:12px; margin-top:20px;\">
            <p><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$url\">READ</a><span style=\"float:right; cursor:pointer;\"><a class=\"delete\">DELETE</a></span></p>
            </div></div>";
            if($i == $start_from + 4) break; 
            }
            }
```

Comment: If you add `parentPanel` class then you can directly use `$('.parentPanel').remove()`.

Comment: @Ajinkya - Not if you assume that these panels are created in a loop.

Comment: @Ajinkya you are missing something as if `$('.parentPanel').remove()` is used then all the `<div>` containing `.parentPanel` class would be removed. Here the requirement is the `<div>` which contains the clicked delete button need to be removed.

Comment: @nnnnnn: loops, I missed them :)

Comment: P.S. Note that [`.parentsUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) gets the ancestors up to _but not including_ the one that matches the selector.

Comment: @nnnnnn yep got your point so here Closest would be the best way to work with. Agreed to you.